# How to use a sprite inside a css notification box? (and not a single image)

Tags: css, notifications, sprite

The Template I use has notication box like text-info, text-alert, text-tip classes, which are color boxes with an icon at the beginning.
I managed to add a lot of different icons, so in order to keep my website quick, I wish to replace the icons by a single sprite.
And so I did.
But... I can't find a way to neatly vertical-align the icon Inside the box...

I would have put a screen capture if only I could, but I'm a newbie here... so you will have to visit this page to see what I am talking about (please remove the spaces aroundd rouchenergies, and when you land on the page, go at the bottom of the article, look for 2 grey notification boxes looking very similar) :

http://www.rouchenergies.fr/qui-sommes-nous/qualifications/rge-qualibois.html

The above box is the template's css, with a single class called text-file-pdf. 
HTML =

```html
<p class="text-file-pdf">bla bla bla</p>
```

The lower box is my css, which needs 2 different classes : 1 for box called "box-gris", 1 for icon called "file-pdf"

HTML =

```html
<p class="box-gris"><span class="file-pdf"></span>bla bla bla</p>
```

Let's have a look to the css :

CSS OF THE TEMPLATE:

```css
.text-file-pdf {
 border-top: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
 background: #f2f2f2 url(../../../images/small-n-flat-master/file-pdf.png) no-repeat;
}
.text-file-pdf {
 background-position: left center;
 padding: 0.8em 0.8em 0.8em 5em;
 min-height: 20px;
}
```

CSS OF MY OWN:

```css
.box-gris {
 border-top: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
 border-bottom: 2px solid #e5e5e5;
 background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.box-gris {
 padding: 0.8em 0.8em 0.8em 5em;
 min-height: 20px;
}

.file-pdf {
 display: inline-block;
 background-image: url(../../../images/small-n-flat-master/sprite-small-n-flat.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 width: 60px;
 height: 24px;
 float: left;
 margin-left: -5em;
 vertical-align: middle;
}
.file-pdf {
 background-position: 0 -1080px;
}
```

I Wonder why the vertical-align: middle; does not work... and/or what I should be doing instead of this?

Any help welcome;)

Comment: float kills display, that's why vertical-align is not avalaible then. remove float. display:flex could be an option too.

Comment: Thank you. I deleted the float, but still not working as I want... But I will have a close lokk to the display:flex; which seems to be exactly what I need! 
As soon as I have tested it, I will come back here to say if it has resolved my "problem".
Thank you for this idea ;)